# Convert Html string to node collection using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, vb.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have this html. I want to get list of node using html agility pack.

```
<span prop="name">Richard Winchester</span>
<span prop="company">Kodak</span>
<span prop="street">Arlington Road 1</span>
```

I tried this

```
Dim doc = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
doc.LoadHtml(AboveHtmlInString)
Dim nodes = doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes
```

But I am not getting collection of nodes.

Comment: Do you get an error? You will need to provide more of your code as the code you provided would appear to work.

Answer (score 1):

Your above code should work. I have made an identical representation in C# and it compiles and works as intended. It might be a visual basic issue.

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(AboveHtmlString);
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes;
```